# Java HashSet 2d array duplicate recognition

Tags: java

I need to check whether a list/set of 2d char arrays contains an exact duplicate of another 2d char array that I pass as a parameter. My idea was to make a `HashSet` and then use the `contains()` method, but that's not really working; I assume it has to do with me passing the method 2D arrays. If possible, I don't want iterate through every item in the list because that is too costly. Please help me out here. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some actual code?

Comment: Costly? And what you think the algorithms that run under the hood do? Magic? Just kidding ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would never work because the `hashCode` of the arrays is based on the `Object`'s so unless you are trying to find same references, you will never get a `contains` to evaluate to `true`.

You should create a wrapper for your arrays and `override` the `hashCode` and `equals`. You can use [Arrays.deepEquals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) for this purpose